# Php countdown, make the div change width for every day

Tags: php, html, width, countdown

Hey i have made a countdown, but what i want is a div that change width after the day.
Let's say there is 150 days back to someday, then i want the div to be 150px in width. Is this possibel? I have seach all over the web.

Comment: Do you know how to set the width of a div? Do you know how to echo a PHP variable? If so: `<div style='width: <?php echo $numDays; ?>px'>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's simple. store start date and update `div` via counting difference with now. Every 150 days re-store start date.
here's some pseudocode

```
var start=17/01/2013 //stored date
func countDifference(){
return differenceIs=now()-start+1;
}
func setWidth(){
div.width=countDifference();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a purely php method, you could assign a class to the div based on the number of days, but then you'd need a css style specified for every single possible width.

It would be better to do it via javascript - Sugar's answer contains a basic method.
You could also use the css method in jQuery to change a css width attribute.
http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing like given below..

```
  <div id="test"  style='background-color:red;color:white;display:block;width:150px;'>asdasdsdasda</div>
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function(e){
         var today = new Date();
         var startday  = new Date('01/15/2013');
         var width = 150;
         var diff = DateDiff(new Date(today),new Date(startday));
         diff = parseInt(diff);
         var val  = parseInt(parseInt(diff) / parseInt(width));

        if( val >= 1 ){
                diff = parseInt(parseIn(diff) - parseInt(width * val));
         }
         var now_width = width - diff;

         $('#test').css('width' , parseInt(now_width));   

         function DateDiff(date1, date2) {

                 var datediff = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime(); 
                 return (datediff / (24*60*60*1000));
          }

        });
      </script>
```

Please check  url given below

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/R7JnU/1/)

I hope it will be helpful for you.
thanks